# Issue With Relationships

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm building some C# code to query my neo4j database and display results in a web page using Cytoscape.js. I am trying to execute this query via code:

```
`MATCH (n) WHERE toLower(n.Name) CONTAINS toLower('spoofing') WITH n MATCH (`n)-[r]-(otherNodes) RETURN n, r, otherNodes
```

When I run this query through neo4j browser I get 58 nodes, 155 relationships. Here is my C# code trying to accomplish the same query:

```
    strSearch = "toLower(n.Name) CONTAINS '" + txtSearchPhrase.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "'";

    var test = client.Cypher
    .Match("(n)")
    .Where(strSearch)
    .With("n")
    .Match("(n)-[r]-(otherNodes)")
    .Return((n, r, otherNodes) => new
    {
    n = n.As<NodeInfo>(),
    r =  Return.As<string>("type(r)"),
    otherNodes = otherNodes.As<NodeInfo>() //otherNodes.CollectAs<NodeInfo>()
    });

    var results = test.Results.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
    Type type = results[i].GetType();

    //JSON node.
    string strSource_id = results[i].n.Type + "_" + results[i].n.Id.ToString();
    string strDest_id = results[i].otherNodes.Type + "_" + results[i].otherNodes.Id.ToString();

    //Source.
    clsWebJsonNode myclsWebJsonNode = new clsWebJsonNode() { Id = results[i].n.Id, id = strSource_id, label = strSource_id , title = results[i].n.Name, Type = results[i].n.Type, objBlob = results[i].n.objBlob, DescriptionSummaryObjective = results[i].n.DescriptionSummaryObjective, CVSS = results[i].n.CVSS, Status = results[i].n.Status, Abstraction = results[i].n.Abstraction };
    NodeColor(ref myclsWebJsonNode);
    string strNodeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myclsWebJsonNode, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    myWebJson.AddNodeJson(strNodeJson);

    //Destination.
    myclsWebJsonNode = new clsWebJsonNode() { Id = results[i].otherNodes.Id, id = strDest_id, label = strDest_id , title = results[i].otherNodes.Name, Type = results[i].otherNodes.Type, objBlob = results[i].otherNodes.objBlob, DescriptionSummaryObjective = results[i].otherNodes.DescriptionSummaryObjective, CVSS = results[i].otherNodes.CVSS, Status = results[i].otherNodes.Status, Abstraction = results[i].otherNodes.Abstraction };
    NodeColor(ref myclsWebJsonNode);
    strNodeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myclsWebJsonNode, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    myWebJson.AddNodeJson(strNodeJson);

    //JSON link.
    clsWebJsonLink myclsWebJsonLink = new clsWebJsonLink() { target = strSource_id, source = strDest_id, label = results[i].r, id = (strSource_id + "--" + results[i].r + "--*" + strDest_id) };
    string strLinkJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myclsWebJsonLink, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    myWebJson.AddLinkJson(strLinkJson);                
    }
```

When I execute this code, I get 58 nodes, 103 relationships. In addition, I'm not sure how to really know which "direction" the relationships are going. I thought 'n' would be considered the source (tail) and 'otherNodes' would be considered the destination (head). But many of my relationship directions aren't matching what is displayed in neo4j browser.

Does anyone have any insight on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to simplify you initial request like so

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(otherNodes) 
WHERE toLower(n.Name) CONTAINS toLower('spoofing') 
RETURN n, r, otherNodes
```

Then you have to provide a direction to you pattern matching if you want `n` to always be your starting node like so (notice the addition of the `>` in the match pattern)

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(otherNodes) 
WHERE toLower(n.Name) CONTAINS toLower('spoofing') 
RETURN n, r, otherNodes
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I did simplify my client code and am playing with the direction arrows. In the end, in the neo4j browser settings there is a check box for "connect result nodes". When I uncheck this, I get my node and relationship numbers to sync up.

Comment: Actually still seeing expediencies. First thing tomorrow I'm going to try running two queries, each with opposite direction arrows to see if I can end up with the same results as neo4j Browser.